# Why Gravity doesn't affect Horizontal acceleration/motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, acceleration, vectors

It is still hard for me to grasp on why gravity doesn't affect horizontal motion, doesnt gravity causes a change in resultant force and thus cause a change in acceleration $F=m.a$

Comment: Please don't add "Thnx in advance" to all your posts. SMS language is _very_ off-putting, and "thank you" stuff are [considered noise on SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/).

Comment: I don't know why this attracted downvotes.  I know it's not the most "glamorous" of questions, but clearly the OP is having a conceptual problem in physics, which is precisely what we claim we try and help with.

Comment: @StephenG People have all sorts of reasons to downvote, and varying beliefs about what aspects of a question deserve downvotes, and that is their right, but personally I agree that this question is not too bad. However it doesn't show any effort on the part of the poster to figure it out themselves. That might account for some downvotes.

Comment: @StéphaneRollandin I'm removing your comment; please keep in mind that comments are for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification, not for answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

The equation you quote $F=ma$ should more strictly be a **vector** equation:
$$\vec{F}=m\vec{a}$$
Now the force and resulting acceleration are vectors, which means they have a magnitude (size) and a direction associated with them.

The Earth is below you, which means it exerts a force with $z$-component (the part of the vector contributing vertically):
$$F_z = -\frac{GM_\text{Earth}m_\text{you}}{R_\text{Earth}^2}$$
or the total force vector acting on you from the Earth below you is
$$\vec{F}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
-\frac{GM_\text{Earth}m_\text{you}}{R_\text{Earth}^2}
\end{pmatrix}$$
and similarly the resulting acceleration vector is
$$\vec{a}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
-\frac{GM_\text{Earth}}{R_\text{Earth}^2}
\end{pmatrix}$$
i.e. the acceleration has size $\frac{GM_\text{Earth}}{R_\text{Earth}^2}$ and direction directly downwards (in the negative $z$-direction).

There is nothing to say that gravity can't act horizontally, and indeed it does all the time!  Whenever you stand next to someone, they exert a gravitational force of attraction towards them, with *horizontal* force component ($x$-component):
$$F_x = -\frac{Gm_\text{friend}m_\text{you}}{d_\text{friend-you}^2}$$
Adding the Earth's pull the total force vector for gravity is now
$$\vec{F}=\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{Gm_\text{friend}m_\text{you}}{d_\text{friend-you}^2}\\
0\\
-\frac{GM_\text{Earth}m_\text{you}}{R_\text{Earth}^2}
\end{pmatrix}$$
and now the direction is not exactly straight down.

Of course in most calculations however, because $M_\text{Earth}$ is so huge, the Earth's gravity swamps gravity from other objects on Earth, and so to a very good approximation, that is the only gravitational force acting on you, and it acts straight down.

Comment: But I don't accelerate towards earth's center...

Comment: Why not? The Earth's center is "down" - there may be some confusion as to whether the Earth is round or flat in this model, and in many situations we just treat the field as uniform and downward pointing, not radial, because it's easier, and a very good local approximation anyway.

Comment: If you want to consider radial gravitational forces, you can and you discover that tidal forces play a role (which is gravity ripping apart an object due to it having finite size, and hence different parts of the object experiencing different gravitational strengths) - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_force

Comment: I don't accelerate because I'm sitting on a chair. I think the reaction force of the chair is missing in OP's mental picture.

Comment: Ah sorry that's what you mean - yes I am **only** considering the force on me due to gravity, but of course there are other forces acting on me (e.g. reaction force from the ground) stopping me from just continuously falling through to the Earth's centre

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbf F$ and $\mathbf a$ in the equation $$\mathbf F=m\mathbf a$$ are *vectors*. That means that, if we set our frame of reference such that $z$ is vertical, then any body subject to gravity will obey the equations
$$\begin{align}0&=ma_x\\0&=ma_y\\mg&=ma_z\end{align}$$
As you can see, the motion along the $x$ and $y$ axes is just the same as it would be if no force was acting on the body.

You can easily see in a similar way that, if the body is subject to both gravity and another force $\mathbf F$, then the motion of the object along the $x$ and $y$ axes is determined only by $\mathbf F$ and not by gravity.